# Single SignOut Issue, it cannot be performed in multiple site

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif

I am using STS for controlling SSO. I got one STS site, and two client site application(site a, site b).

Both of site a and site b have added the STS site as their STS reference. The single sign on is working fine, I can just login once, however, the single sign out is not working.

In both Site a and site b, I have implemented FederatedPassiveSignInStatus control below.

```
<wif:FederatedPassiveSignInStatus ID="FederatedPassiveSignInStatus1" runat="server" 
    SignOutAction="FederatedPassiveSignOut" OnSignedOut="OnSigOut_click" />
```

OnSigOut_click:

```
public void OnSigOut_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CookieHandler.Delete();
    FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();
    FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
    FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignOut(false);
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();

}
```

If I signout from site A first and then refresh site B, Site A will redirect to STS login login page, Site B is still in the same page with the same login info.

Can anyone know how to do the single sign out/off?

Comment: var fam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;


        var signOutRequestMessage = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(fam.Issuer), fam.Realm);
        var signOutURI = signOutRequestMessage.WriteQueryString();
        fam.SignOut();
        Response.Redirect(signOutURI, false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WSFederationAuthenticationModule. Add below module to web.config

```
<modules><add name="WsFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/></modules>
```

Use following approach. Take it as an example.

```
WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
fam.FederatedSignOut(STSSignOutAbsoluteURL,RPReturnURL);
```

Comment: Thanks your advice!, I have tried it, It does not work, the "ThreadAbortException" break the SignOut action, when I click Back button and refresh the site, the login info still stay in the page.

Comment: Happy to know you found a solution. Add it as an answer to help someone searching similar problem.

Comment: =.=||, It is not working, ThreadAbortException break the Signout action

Comment: moreover, I have to find some ways to call ?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0 back to the client site. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.federatedsignout.aspx

AND 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.getfederationpassivesignouturl.aspx

Comment: Finally, I found the reason, if I filled 'null' in the method WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(null, null), I will not have the ThreadAbortException, and ss-out is working fine.